# Where to ask question regarding any framework/packages to reuse (within Stack Overflow or out)?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am a web/mobile .NET developer and sometimes (due to extremely fast development of technologies) I might miss the appearance of some new frameworks/packages I could reuse. However, I am not quite sure where I can ask the questions like "is there any such one for this or that?"

So, for example, what is the appropriate section of Stack Exchange (or any other websites) I should use for anything like that, including .NET-referring?

(I am just not 100% sure if this is quite related to stackoverflow.com (base) scope.)

Comment: Under strict conditions some might fit on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Such questions are definitely off-topic on SO.